# Changing InnerHtml Of Button Loses Styling Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a function that I call on a buttons onclick event called "toggleCollapse". I want to change the innet text of the button from "Collapse" to "Expand" when clicked. The code below does that but also loses all the jquery mobile styleing of the button in the process. How can I refresh the styling of the button without having to reload the entire page, I just want to refresh the buttons styling nothing else.

```
<a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="grid" iconpos="right" onclick="toggleCollapse()">Collapse</a>

function toggleCollapse() {
    var a = $("#collapse_value")
                .attr("value");
    var b;
    if (a == "false") {

        $("#btnCollapse").html("Expand");

        b = true
    } else {

        $("#btnCollapse").html("Collapse");

    }


    $('#btnCollapse').button();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to "change the innet text of the button from `Collapse` to `Expand` when clicked", why not use the `.text()` function instead of the `.html()` function.

The `.html()` function maps to the `innerHTML` property.

The `.text()` function maps to the `innerText` property.

```
function toggleCollapse() {
    var a = !! $('#collapse_value').val(); //use !! to convert value to a boolean
    $('#btnCollapse').text(a ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse');
}
```

This should replace the text label for the button without affecting the style, however you may instead want to use the `.button()` method for changing the button label (since you appear to be using the jQuery UI buttons). Here's an example:

```
function toggleCollapse() {
    var a = !! $('#collapse_value').val(); //use !! to convert value to a boolean
    $('#btnCollapse').button('option', 'label', a ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding inline onClick calls because it can be management hassle if you ever need to change it across several pages/button.  Instead just apply a class to the button/a href.

```
<a data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="grid" iconpos="right" class="toggleCollapse btn">Collapse</a>

(function(){

  $('.toggleCollapse').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).text( ($(this).text() == 'Collapse') ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse' );
  });

$('.btn').button();

})()​;​
```

A working example can be found at [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n3LhC/4/)

Comment: I need to keep the inline onClick. I need a way to do this with the inline onclick. I tried setting the .html() it changes the name correctly but the jquery mobile prettyness is lost eventhough the markup is correct